# Google app engine / Google Apps domain charging

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

I have managed to get my new Google App Engine APp hosted on my domain. TO do this I had to sign up to a "free" google apps account.

The google apps account is asking for money and I have a free 30 day trial. Will my domain name that Google App Engine is using stop working when this 30 day trial is up?

Do I have to pay $5 a month or whatever it is just to have my google app engine app hosted on a domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to pay.

You can get a free single-user Google Apps account. See "Serving Your App on a Custom Domain" at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain?hl=en

Comment: Aha - yes I had found that Add Domain option but I had not seen the free apps account link.
This video helps:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=UnjrqtsL1hg
Now I need to delete my other apps account and move the domain to a free apps account...

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

> To serve your app on a custom domain, you must first associate that domain with a Google Apps account.

From
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

Comment: I've already done this but the "free" apps accoutn will expire in 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do need a Google Apps Account, and No you don't need to pay for it.

When you sign up for a new AppEngine account you should go for an option to create a new Apps Account, where you will be given an apps account with one user. This will be free. See this: http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-apps-free/26926/

Answer (score 0):

NO, You can use a cname to go your app engine domain (www.example.com  --> example.appspot.com)
But, this does not work for a naked domain, like example.com Your provider (most providers) can redirect all your domain traffic to your app_id.

Comment: The OP is asking if he needs a Google Apps Account to make this work and the answer is yes.

Comment: @Peter. I followed the link. You are right. Is that a new requirement? Since when? I cannot remember doing that?

Answer (score 0):

As of now it seems that you have to sign up for a business account and get a $50 credit for 1 year, after which time Google will have a better solution.

See this thread for sympathetic dissatisfaction.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/pVZfdeky-ow/TO1SmipM2Y0J

(Wish the Google support person told me that *before* I deleted the business account I already had...)

Comment: OK I don't expect this is a standard result, but after signing up for business, then deleting my business account and 10 minutes later 'adding the domain' again from App Engine, I logged in with my formerly deleted business account credentials and it's taken me into a non-billing, 1 user account.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's an old question, but the marked answer is not right anymore. Google is pushing everybody who want a custom domain to pay for business account.

However there is one **workaround**:

1. Go to AppEngine -> Application Settings -> Add domain -> Sign up for Google Apps
2. Start a free 30 day trial - Do not add the billing options
3. Setup your domain
4. Add the domain to your app engine project
5. When the 30 day trial expire the domain will still **work**.